# Can I use jOOQ to map a plain SQL query into a generated pojo?

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I'm executing a plain sql query in jOOQ and would like to map it into a jOOQ generated pojo. I was hoping that I could to something like this:

```
public List<Foo> findFoos(final DateTime time) {
    return db.resultQuery(loadSqlQuery("FooRepository_findFoos"), time)
             .fetchInto(Foo.class);
}
```

However this does not work. The fields do not get mapped to the types required to build a `Foo` as the field definitions are those of the DB columns, not the mapped types of the FOO table. Currently my code looks something like this:

```
public List<Foo> findFoos(final DateTime time) {
    return db.resultQuery(loadSqlQuery("FooRepository_findFoos"), time)
             .fetch(r -> {
                 return new Foo(
                         new FooId(r.getValue(FOO.ID, UUID.class)),
                         new BarId(r.getValue(FOO.BAR_ID, UUID.class))
                         //etc
                 );
             });
}
```

Is there some way I can provide the result query with the list of `Field`s that I am fetching so it can map the result correctly? I am hoping that somewhere there is the ability to do something like this instead:

```
public List<Foo> findFoos(final DateTime time) {
    return db.resultQuery(loadSqlQuery("FooRepository_findFoos"), time)
             .fetch(FOO.fields())
             .into(Foo.class);
}
```

However I can't find it. Is this a thing somewhere that I am overlooking or is this not supported?

For reference, one of the reasons I am using plain sql is to get intervals to work in PostgreSQL. e.g (not the real query)

```
select
    f.*
from foo f
where f.id not in (
    select
        x.foo_id
    from bar x
    where x.start_date >= (?::timestamptz - '1 year'::interval)
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.6.x/org/jooq/util/postgres/PostgresUtils.html

Comment: Yes. Afaict that does not provide the functionality I am looking for. This question is more about the mapping that the interval stuff though.

Comment: @assylias I take that back, it does solve my issue re intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### jOOQ 3.12 solution

jOOQ 3.12 implements [#4473](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4473), which allows for coercing a `ResultQuery<R1>` to a new, well-known record type `ResultQuery<R2>` (possibly with `Converter` or `Binding` configurations).

You could write:

```
public List<Foo> findFoos(final DateTime time) {
    return db.resultQuery(loadSqlQuery("FooRepository_findFoos"), time)
             .coerce(FOO)
             .fetch();
}
```

#### Workaround for jOOQ 3.11 and earlier versions

You don't necessarily have to resort to all-plain SQL. You could do this instead:

```java
public List<Foo> findFoos(final DateTime time) {
    return db.select(FOO.fields())
             .from("({0}) AS {1}", 
                  DSL.sql(loadSqlQuery("FooRepository_findFoos"), time),
                  DSL.name(FOO.getName()))
             .fetchInto(Foo.class);
}
```

You'd have to make sure that `FOO.fields()` doesn't generate any schema names, e.g. by specifying `Settings.renderSchema = false`

Comment: That workaround is great, does exactly what I want. Thanks.